# Adding a new element to select box after the first option element using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a combobox with the following options

```
<select id="history">
    <option></option>
    <option>element1</option>
    <option>element2</option>
    <option>element3</option>
    <option>element4</option>
</select>
```

I'm trying to add a new option after the first option. What is the best most effective way to accomplish this I tried

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#history").prepend("<option>sdsadas</option>").after('#history:first-child');
    $("<option>asdsad</option>").insertBefore('#history option:first-child');
//    $('option[value="sadsaddsad"]', this).after('option:first');
</script>
```

but none of these are working as I want.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$("#history option:first").after("<option>sdsadas</option>");
```

This gets the first `<option>` tag and then inserts a new option after it.

---

jQuery supports two ways of inserting in a position.  The above version is `target.after(content)` and this other way is `content.insertAfter(target)`:

```
$("<option>sdsadas</option>").insertAfter("#history option:first");
```

Note: One uses `.after()` and the other uses `.insertAfter()`.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
$("#history option:eq(0)").after("<option>New Option Added</option>");
```

Source: http://www.myphpetc.com/2009/03/jquery-select-elements-tips-and-tricks.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
$("<option>asdsad</option>").insertBefore($('#history option:first-child'));
```

Instead of:

```
$("<option>asdsad</option>").insertBefore('#history option:first-child');
```